# Bash: immediately terminate current subcommand and script

Tags: bash, scripting

I want pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>^<kbd>C</kbd> to immediately terminate the current running subcommand and the bashscript itself.

Minimal script:

```bash
install_packages="python-wheel\
                  make\
                  python-setproctitle\
                  python-distro"
remove_packages="libnotify\
                 python-setuptools\
                 python-distutils-extra"

sudo pamac install $install_packages
sudo pamac remove $install_packages
```

So I want to terminate the current pamac installation and also the script itself so the *pamac remove* does not even start.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of bash when executing a script file. The interrupt signal will terminate the process that's executing the script. The currently executing command in the script will stop and any further ones will not be executed.

```
✔ ~$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.0.17(1)-release
✔ ~$ echo "echo 1
> sleep 5
> echo 2
> " > t.sh
✔ ~$ bash t.sh
1
^C
✘-INT ~$
```